# Minidlna not indexing new files

Tags: openwrt

I've installed minidlna on my Turris Omnia router, which runs OpenWrt:

```
# /usr/bin/minidlna -V
Version 1.2.1

# uname -a
Linux turris 4.4.167-4a7a81f8db0ad743e54c68e1845c60b6-1 #1 SMP Tue Dec 18 11:40:26 CET 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

When I add a file (via FTP) to the directory that is watched by the service, it isn't indexed (even after 900 seconds).  When I delete a file, however, the indexed is updated immediately.

I've found that the only way to get new context indexed is to delete the `/var/run/minidlna` directory, then restart the service.

I looked at the content of `/var/run/minidlna/files.db` and verified that the new file is not in the database.

To complicate matters, it doesn't appear that the `log_level` setting has any effect on `/var/log/minidlna`--it's pretty terse.

How do I fix this?

`/etc/config/minidlna:`

```
config minidlna 'config'
    option port '8200'
    option interface 'br-lan'
    option db_dir '/var/run/minidlna'
    option log_dir '/var/log'
    option log_level 'general,artwork,database,inotify,scanner,metadata,http,ssdp=debug'
    option inotify '1'
    option notify_interval '900'
    option serial '12345678'
    option model_number '1'
    option root_container '.'
    option album_art_names 'Cover.jpg/cover.jpg/AlbumArtSmall.jpg/albumartsmall.jpg/AlbumArt.jpg/albumart.jpg/Album.jpg/album.jpg/Folder.jpg/folder.jpg/Thumb.jpg/thumb.jpg'
    option friendly_name 'Turris'
    list media_dir 'V,/mnt/raid/Media/Movies'
    list media_dir 'V,/mnt/raid/Media/Series'
    list media_dir 'V,/mnt/raid/Media/Videos'
    list media_dir 'P,/mnt/raid/Media/Pictures'
    list media_dir 'A,/mnt/raid/Media/Music'
    option enabled '1'
```